# how to split the string in LINQ?

Tags: asp.net, string, linq

I have to bind the search results in the grid view based on search criteria. In my database primary store id value is like 10,12. When I select particular primary store id from the dropdown list i.e. 10, the search result corresponding to that primary store id need to be shown in the grid view.How to do that?

```
public static List<SearchKeyWord> GetAllKeywords(string key,  
        string primaryStoreId, string keywordStatus, int keywordId, 
        string categoryName, string subCategoryName)
{ 
    keys = db.SearchKeyWords.Where(c => c.KeyWord.Contains(key) && 
    (c.PrimaryStoreID == primaryStoreId || 
    c.PrimaryStoreID.Split(',').ToList().Contains(primaryStoreId)) && 
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryName) || c.StoreCategoryMapping == categoryName) && 
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(subCategoryName) || c.StoreSubCategoryMapping == 
    subCategoryName)).ToList();
}
```

**Edited!**

Comment: I think he means he is actually just using an integer primary key - just not explaining himself clearly... The OP might like to try and clarify the question a bit... Things I notice straight away though are that there are a lot of unnecessary calls to the ToList() method, and that he's not actually returning the keys variable. I doubt this code compiles as it is...

Comment: @MartinMilan, Primary store id is actually a string. I have mapped multiple ids for primary store id with ','. That primary store ids are loaded in the drop down list one by one. when i select a particular primary id from the drop down list and search that store id, i have to bind results corresponding to store id in the grid view. For example I have mapped 25,50 to the particular store id column in the database. When I select only 25 from the drop down list and click search button, then the result corresponding to matched store id available in the database need to be shown in the grid view.

Comment: What is the actual question?  What does or doesn't work?  Right now all we can say is that that primary Id is a questionable design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption -- search db.SearchKeyWords for all elements in which attribute PrimaryStoreID (a comma separated list) contains Key.

```
public static List<SearchKeyWord> GetAllKeywords(string key,  
        string primaryStoreId, string keywordStatus, int keywordId, 
        string categoryName, string subCategoryName)
{ 
    return db.SearchKeyWords
      .Where(c => c.PrimaryStoreID.Split(",".ToCharArray()).Contains(key));
}
```

Not clear at all what you want to do with the other parameters.